# wpf - start a process and exit application

Tags: wpf, process

The WPF application loads an xml file which has a list of Apps to install.

I use

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(setupFilePath, commandLineArguments);
```

To install one of the Apps this wpf application needs to be exited. I tried the following code before calling `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(setupFilePath,commandLineArguments);`

it still doesn't close.

```
System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit();
System.Windows.Application.Current.Shutdown(1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `Environment.Exit()` instead